# What component/device to use for a front-eye display

Tags: components, display

I need to display information in front of my eyes, just like Google Glass, but in this case, it has to fill a bigger field of view (is it the good term?). I have already thought about a couple ways to do it, but I am not sure they be relevant :

1) Using reflection on a piece of glass, with a screen on a side. In this case, how can I make the reflection work, what kind of materials to use, the nature of the side screen ?

2) Some type of micro-projector

If possible I would like to plug it as an external display, to a simple computer, running any OS, and it is a plus if it can be displayed on a pair of glasses.

Comment: [news blurb](http://www.theregister.co.uk/2013/02/22/google_glass_patent/) about Google Glass Patent.

Comment: Why the down-votes?  Not a question using electronics in all of the solution BUT it is asking about an electronics related requirement which is liable to be of interest to many. 
+1 :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The requirement is technically "easy" [tm].
 It's "just a matter of doing it".
 Making it compact and pretty may be harder :-).

"All" you need is a display with the resolution, size, weight, brightness and power consumption that you require and a lensing system to reduce the viewing distance to what is acceptable relative to your eye. A mirror or prism may be used to change direction by 90 degrees or some other angle.

---

Superb example of what can be achieved can be viewed (literally) in any of the SONY DSLR cameras which have OLED EVF displays instead of an optical viewfinder. The Sony A77 camera with XGA (1027 x 768) electronic viewfinder has perhaps the best example but there are others with  lesser resolution

[Excellent A77 EVF review](http://www.imaging-resource.com/PRODS/AA77/AA77A3.HTM)

A77 eyepoint to lens is 27mm  -  which shows you what can be achieved.

---

A much cheaper way to start is to obtain some cheap +4 diopter reading glasses
($2 / pair here - YMMV), take out the lenses and look at your display with 1, 2, 3, 4, ... stacked together.

1 x +4 diopter lens gives you a ~= 1/4 = 0.25 metre = 250 mm viewing distance.
2 x +4 diopter lenses stacked (in close contact) gives you
8 diopter =  1/8 m focusing distance  = 125 mm viewing distance.
3 gives you ~= 83 mm
4 gives you ~= 60 mm or about 2.4 inches.
...
Or stacking lower diopter lenses or a mixed set may give you better results.

Putting on several pairs of spectacles at once and looking at a book gives you some idea of what to expect.  Quite reasonable quality can be achieved with cheap lenses. If you get serious enough you can get N diopter lenses ground to your specification.